# Mixing Higgses and sneutrinos

Tags: supersymmetry

I have a question which might have a trivial answer, but since I am not sure about it I'll ask it anyway.

When working in supersymmetric models, one usually has at least 2 Higgs doublets. Assuming CP invariance, one separates the CP even and CP odd Higgses, i.e.  the real and imaginary components (real fields) of the complex Higgs fields, and thus one has two mass matrices. One can change the basis of the space defined by these real fields, particularly when one wants to diagonalise the mass matrices.

As far as I know, we can mix different fields by rotations or any change of basis as long as such changes leave the equation of motion invariant (i.e. the Lagrangian remains invariant under the symmetries of the system). So my question is, why can't we mix sneutrinos with Higgses, for instance? Which symmetry would be violated?

Comment: ...is it Lepton number or other accidental symmetry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is, why can't we mix sneutrinos with Higgses, for instance? Which symmetry would be violated?

It seems that the answer is short: **This is R-parity.** Normal particles (including all 5 Higgs bosons) are R-even and superpartners are R-odd, so they cannot mix if R-parity is unbroken. If it is broken, higgson-sneutrino mixing is possible (and sometimes people talk about it), but also [quick proton decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay#Dimension-4_proton_decay_operators) and decay of the lightest supersymmetric particle are possible. Without R-symmetry, the Higgs boson can even be sneutrino, but [there are some problems](http://motls.blogspot.com/2014/07/isnt-higgs-sneutrino-dressed-as-man.html).

R-symmetry is also the simplest way for lepton number to stay accidental symmetry of MSSM.